# How do you specify a byte literal in Java?

Tags: java, byte, literals

If I have a method

```
void f(byte b);
```

how can I call it with a numeric argument without casting?

```
f(0);
```

gives an error.

Comment: @oliholz that's downcasting with additional parsing overhead

Answer (score 331, accepted):

You cannot. A basic numeric constant is considered an integer (or long if followed by a "L"), so you must explicitly downcast it to a byte to pass it as a parameter. As far as I know there is no shortcut.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of this sort of thing, you can define a simple helper method `byte b(int i) { return (byte) i; }` somewhere and statically import it. Then you can write f(b(10)).

Answer (score 147):

You have to cast, I'm afraid:

```
f((byte)0);
```

I believe that will perform the appropriate conversion at *compile*-time instead of *execution* time, so it's not actually going to cause performance penalties. It's just inconvenient :(

Comment: +1 for compile-time conversion.  It's common sense if you both understand compilers and have faith in language designers (which we should), but otherwise not so obvious.

Answer (score 37):

You can use a byte literal in Java... sort of.

```
    byte f = 0;
    f = 0xa;
```

`0xa` (int literal) gets automatically cast to byte. It's not a real byte literal (see JLS & comments below), but [if it quacks like a duck, I call it a duck.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

What you can't do is this:

```
void foo(byte a) {
   ...
}

 foo( 0xa ); // will not compile
```

You have to cast as follows:

```
 foo( (byte) 0xa );
```

But keep in mind that these will all compile, and they are using "byte literals":

```
void foo(byte a) {
   ...
}

    byte f = 0;

    foo( f = 0xa ); //compiles

    foo( f = 'a' ); //compiles

    foo( f = 1 );  //compiles
```

Of course this compiles too

```
    foo( (byte) 1 );  //compiles
```

Comment: These are not byte literals. They are literals of a variety of other types (int, mostly) that are being implicitly converted to a byte.

e.g., `1` is an int literal, but `double d = 1;` compiles just fine.

Comment: If you're already using tricks. Have a static import of `byte b(int i){}`, then `b(1)` as long and less tricky than `f=1`.

Comment: @smehmood, But since the conversion is done by the pre-compiler/compiler (before the program even starts running) and not the runtime, then it is a literal isn't it?

Comment: @Pacerier It is a literal. It is not a "byte literal". It is an int. The compiler treats it as an int literal (as it should) and does an implicit downcast in the assignment (as it also should). At no point is it parsed as a "byte literal" (which does not exist). See [JLS Section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) in particular the latter half concerning narrowing conversions. The only things involved are an integer constant and the application of an appropriate assignment conversion rule to a byte variable.

Comment: I gave this answer +1 because the technique is novel, but indeed, there ain't no "byte literals" in Java.

Answer (score 13):

If you're passing literals in code, what's stopping you from simply declaring it ahead of time?

```
byte b = 0; //Set to desired value.
f(b);
```

Comment: This also allows you to give the value a more semantic name. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: This is useful. If you're trying to fill an array of bytes using java's 'fill' method, this is most sensible.

Comment: The compiler just complained about the following, however, and I needed to add the cast:  `public static final byte BYTE_MASK = ( byte )0xff;`

Comment: And I realized that I actually wanted `byte BYTE_MASK = 0x000000ff;` lest I get some nasty sign extension bugs.

Answer (score 5):

What about overriding the method with

```
void f(int value)
{
  f((byte)value);
}
```

this will allow for `f(0)`

Comment: -1 This is very bad for code readability. And could cause problems when people actually try to pass in a value higher than the byte can hold. I discourage people from using this method!

Comment: Also, this cast will happen at run-time.  Very bad.

Comment: Completely agreeing with Rolf (Tsu), it's perhaps worth adding, that technically it's overloading, not overriding.

Comment: This is not how you should use overriding, and this can inject a lot of errors for the users. casting is something that ensures the type safety.

Answer (score -3):

With Java 7 and later version, you can specify a byte literal in this way:
`byte aByte = (byte)0b00100001;`

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Comment: *binary* literal != *byte* literal.

Comment: you are still down casting to byte.