# Why do I have to cast 0 to byte when the method argument is byte?

Tags: java

Why do I have to cast 0 to `byte` when the method argument is `byte`?

**Example:**

```
void foo() {
   bar((byte) 0);
}

void bar(byte val) {}
```

I know that if the argument is of type long I don't have to cast it, so I'm guessing that Java thinks of mathematical integers as integers runtime.

Doesn't it discourage the usage of byte/short?

Comment: Here is a similar question that covers yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193883/how-do-you-specify-a-byte-literal-in-java

Comment: You are asking about the difference. What should `(byte) Integer.MAX_VALUE` evaluate to? How about `(byte) 512`?

Comment: @Stefan I am more of asking why doesn't java understand that 0 WILL fit into a byte. I know that integer to byte might cause data loss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The literal `0` is an integer, and there is no automatic cast from integer -> byte, due to a potential loss of precision.  For example, `(byte)1024` is outside the valid range.  Perhaps the compiler could be smarter and allow this for small integer literals, but it doesn't...

Widening to long is okay, since every integer can be a long with no loss of information.

And yes, for this reason I would almost never use short or byte in any APIs exposed by my code (although it would be fine for intermediate calculations)

Comment: ++1 for the compiler should be smarter for literals. I like your icon, sir unicorn.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. "Perhaps the compiler could be smarter and allow this for small integer literals, but it doesn't" +1

Comment: It is not the compiler at all -- it is the (Java) *language specification* and this is just how Java was specified. (A Java compiler that acted differently would go against the specification.) C# on the other hand, will nicely "widen up literals" starting at the smallest sized type but, once again, this is per (C#) *language specification*.

Comment: @pst: Then the language specification needs an updated. Semantics.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall As far as I am concerned the entire Java language needs to be rewritten/redesigned ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Because `0` is an `int` literal, and down-casting to `byte` from `int` requires an explicit cast (since there is the possibility of information loss.) You don't need an explicit cast from `int` to `long`, since no information could be lost in that conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Integer literals are implicitly of type `int`, unless they are explicitly marked as `long` through an `L` suffix. There are no corresponding markers for `short` or `byte`.

> Doesn't it discourage the usage of byte/short?

Perhaps it does, and rightfully so. There is no advantage in using individual bytes or shorts, and they often cause problems, especially since the introduction of autoboxing.