# Implicit type cast not working for method parameters?

Tags: java, casting

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class TypeCast{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    byte by = 4;     //compiler casts int literal to byte

    doCasting(4);    //Compilation Error: external type casting is required. WHY ?

  }

  public static void doCasting(byte by){

  }

}
```

I think above code snippet is quite self-explanatory. While `int` literal assignment to `byte` type, compiler does the required cast automatically. Same thing does not happen when we call a method taking `byte` parameter with int literal. Why?

Comment: You cannot. A basic numeric constant is considered an integer, so you must explicitly downcast it to a byte to pass it as a parameter. As far as I know there is no shortcut. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193883/how-do-you-specify-a-byte-literal-in-java)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the difference between an *assignment context* ([JLS 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)) and an *invocation context* ([JLS 5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)) for conversions.

Assignment context conversions include:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

That *isn't* present in the invocation context conversions.

It's not clear to me why the language was designed that way, other than to possibly simplify overload resolution - if you had:

```
doCasting(5);
...
doCasting(int x) {}
doCasting(byte b) {}
```

then you could argue for either of them being the "best match" - `byte` is a more specific type than `int`, but if you think of the literal as being of type `int`, then the `byte` overload makes requires a conversion whereas the `int` overload doesn't.

By making the `byte` overload simply not applicable, the question is removed.

Comment: Agreeing with "overload resolution". Alternative: introduce byte type suffix in addition to L.

Comment: @laune: Sure, that's a great alternative. I was more looking at what was already present than trying to think of remedies :)

Comment: I wouldn't call that "great", what with ...B lurking there for binary even way back then, or 0x10B. Even the 'L' is a necessary eviL.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if Java would have been better off not having the types `short` and `byte`, but instead just having methods to access octets and halfwords within an array of words.  Being able to pack 8- and 16-bit data in an array is certainly useful, but the only advantage I've ever observed for `byte` vs `int` is that the compiler won't squawk if one tries to store the former into a `byte[]`.