# How numeric promotion and demotion works for literals and variables in Java?

Tags: java, variables, type-conversion, literals, type-promotion

I'm not sure if my question is clear enough, so I will give examples. Let's think we have the next expression:

```
byte byteNumber = 10 * 10;
```

I understand the literal number `10` is an integer by default, so the expression `10 * 10` also results in an integer, BUT Java "demotes" it to a byte value since the variable (where the result is stored) is a byte.

However, why this works different?

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;

byte byteNumber = x * y;
```

The line byte `byteNumber = x * y;` is marked as an error. I understand the expression `x * y` results in an integer but is not "demoted" as with the literals. Even if there is only one variable, like `x * 10`, the result won't be demoted. Why exactly? I believe it has something to do with the variables type, but literals are integers by default and they can get "demoted".

Another example I am struggling with is: we can assign integers literals to variables of type byte, short or char, and Java will automatically convert the integer into the type of variable we have declared, like:

```
short a = 10;
byte b = 12;
```

On the other hand, why can't we do something like this?

```
float c = 12.0;
```

Yes, `12.0` is a double, but why can't it be "demoted" to float and forces us to declare the literal as a float `12.0F`? I understand this would represent a lose of information. However, converting an integer to a short or byte also represents a lose of information, isn't it?

Finally, why can we assign a integer literal to a variable of type short or byte...

```
 short a = 10;
 byte b = 12;
```

but we cannot pass an integer as argument to a method that expects a short/byte parameter?

```
public void newMethod(short x, byte y){
    ...
}
```

.
.
.

```
newMethod(10, 2)
```

It would be great if you could search some links where I can read this kind of stuff (since I'm not really sure how to search for these specific issues I have).

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The compiler can determine that literal values are within the appropriate range. Once you assign the value to a variable of a type `int` it can't check anymore.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So you are basically saying that once I wrap a literal with a variable the compiler cannot determine if the value of that literal exceeds the range of (let's say) a byte or a short?

Comment: @YuliyaSheludyakova Yes, it actually clarified almost everything. Still I don't really get why a literal (not a variable) of type `int` (for example `10`) cannot be pass to a method that requires a `byte`, `short` or `char` parameter.

Comment: @DamianGDO Compilers are very good. But they are not sentient. You don't wrap a literal with a variable, you assign a value to a variable. `int a = 100;` assign `100` to `a`. Legal. `byte b = a;` - assign the value in the variable `a` (an `int`) to the `byte` `b` - compiler will not assume that is a valid assignment (unless you tell it). `byte b = (byte) a;` (Hey, I'm the developer. And I know that's safe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the following two links out:

- [Why explicit type casting required from double to float but not from int to byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361456/why-explicit-type-casting-required-from-double-to-float-but-not-from-int-to-byte)
   (the one I have already shared in a comment)
- [Implicit type cast not working for method parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405325/implicit-type-cast-not-working-for-method-parameters)

By the way, both of those questions were answered by the #1 StackOverflow contributor Jon Skeet :)