# Switch on a Byte

Tags: switch-statement, kotlin, literals

How can I switch on a `Byte` value? The obvious way would be:

```
fun foo(b: Byte): Boolean {
  return when(b) {
    0 -> true
    else -> false
  }
}
```

but that fails at compile time with

```
src/ByteSwitch.kt:3:5: error: incompatible types: kotlin.Int and kotlin.Byte
    0 -> true
    ^
```

Is there a way to make that `0` be a byte literal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Kotlin allows branch conditions to be arbitrary expressions (not necessarily constants), one approach is to accept that the `0` will be an `Int` and simply convert it explicitly to a `Byte`:

```
fun foo(b: Byte): Boolean {
  return when(b) {
    0.toByte() -> true
    else -> false
  }
}
```

Per [Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869184/ilya), "`0.toByte()` is evaluated at compile time, so there's no cost of conversion at runtime."

Comment: How inefficient is this if I am going to be doing this in a tight loop?

Comment: You can extract  `0.toByte()` into a local variable for efficiency. Not sure JIT doesn't do it already thou

Comment: `0.toByte()` is evaluated at compile time, so there's no cost of conversion at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify a byte literal in Kotlin ([nor can you in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193919/3255152)). From [Literal Constants - Basic Types - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#literal-constants)

> There are the following kinds of literal constants for integral
>   values:
>
> - Decimals: `123`
>
>   - Longs are tagged by a capital `L`: `123L`
> - Hexadecimals: `0x0F`
> - Binaries: `0b00001011`

You can however declare [compiler-time constants](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants) to avoid run-time overhead:

```
const val ZERO_BYTE: Byte = 0

fun foo(b: Byte): Boolean {
    return when (b) {
        ZERO_BYTE -> true
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Inspecting the Kotlin bytecode further reveals that as `0.toByte()` can be determined at compile-time you can in fact inline the evaluation with no additional run-time overhead:

```
fun foo(b: Byte): Boolean {
    return when (b) {
        0.toByte() -> true
        else -> false
    }
}
```