# Representing numbers without casting in Java

Tags: java, syntax, casting, byte, constants

Does a more natural way to represent those numbers without the use of casting exist in Java?

```
float tolerance = (float) 8.0e-7;
byte[] data = new byte[]{(byte) 0xFF , (byte) 0x15};
```

Not using casting on those instances just doesn't work at all, and it just looks weird when you are defining constants of a primitive type and you have to use casting to represent it (it is like you are saying that Java doesn't support those data types naturally which is ridiculous).

I understand that for the float number you can represent it like this:

```
float tolerance = 0.0000008f;
```

but it is just almost unreadable in this form.

Comment: `0x15` will standalone without the cast. `0xff` needs the cast because bytes are signed in java and gets interpreted as `-1`

Comment: @conscells Followup: So `-0x01` would actually work without cast as replacement for `(byte) 0xFF`. Or just `-1`.

Comment: both should work if i'm not wrong

Comment: @conscells I actually didn't know that there is cases that I don't need to cast bytes, that was new information for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For float values, you can simply express within the literal that you want a **float**, and not a double (which requires the cast):

```
float tolerance =  8.0e-7F;
```

There is no literal for bytes though (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193883/how-do-you-specify-a-byte-literal-in-java)).

Comment: You can even drop the `.0` when using `f`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. But he asked this way; so I will keep it for the moment.

Comment: I wish a similar solution existed for bytes but thank you for your answer @GhostCat