# byte from Enum class without cast

Tags: java, enums

It's possible to have an enum with byte values instead of int values in Java ?

```
public enum PacketTypes {
    REQUEST_CO_SERVER, ACCEPTANCE, REFUSAL, REQUEST_CO_USER, PUBLIC_MSG, PRIVATE_MSG
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*with byte values instead of int values*"? `Enum`s have neither a `byte`- nor an `int`-value. --- This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: enum  work much like an class, you can add fields and methods to it. Similar to:`enum PacketType { REQUEST_CO_SERVER((byte)10), ... ; private final byte code; private PacketType(byte code) { this.code = code; } public byte getCode() { return code; } }`

Comment: define custom constructor to assign byte-value for every enumeration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Comment by user15244370](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446735/byte-from-enum-class-without-cast#comment117469543_66446735) and in the [correct Answer by Tomáš Záluský](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66446839/642706), here is example code of an enum carrying a `byte` member field initialized with value passed to an enum constructor.

By the way, the name of your enum should be singular rather than plural, `PacketType` rather than `PacketTypes`.

```java
enum PacketType {
    ACCEPTANCE ( (byte) 101 ), // Calling constructor on this enum class.
    REFUSAL ( (byte) 42 ) ;
    
    // Member field.
    private byte byteCode ;
    
    // Constructor.
    PacketType ( byte b ) { this.byteCode = b ; }
    
    // Getter method, for a read-only property of this enum.
    byte getByteCode() { return this.byteCode ; }
    
}
```

Here I am using casting of an `int` to get a `byte`. Apparently Java does not offer syntax for a `byte` literal. See [*How do you specify a byte literal in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5193883/642706).

Now see that enum in use with the following [code running live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/E0N1Q4).

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println( 
            PacketType.REFUSAL.toString() 
            + " = " 
            + PacketType.REFUSAL.getByteCode() 
        ) ;
    }
}

enum PacketType {
    ACCEPTANCE ( (byte) 101 ),                     // Calling constructor on this enum class.
    REFUSAL ( (byte) 42 ) ;
    
    private byte byteCode ;                        // Member field.
    
    PacketType ( byte b ) { this.byteCode = b ; }  // Constructor.
    
    byte getByteCode() { return this.byteCode ; }  // Getter method, for a read-only property of this enum.
    
}
```

> REFUSAL = 42

Answer (score 4):

The Java Enum is a [type-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) implementation where you actually don't care what type your constants map to. Strictly speaking, the answer to your question is "no" since the `java.lang.Enum.ordinal` is baked as `int`.

If you are looking for some implementation of bit flags, you might want [java.util.BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

As [commented by @user15244370](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446735/byte-from-enum-class-without-cast#comment117469543_66446735), if you want to associate a value with each enum object, such as a byte value, declare a member field on the enum. Add a constructor that takes the desired value for each enum object to be stored on the member field.

Comment: thanks, but Turing85 is correct [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446735/byte-from-enum-class-without-cast#comment117469501_66446735)